# Meaning of "So yeah"

Tags: meaning

I often hear that phrase at the end of sentences. Sometimes at the beginning. What does it mean?

Comment: So yeah: http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=so+yeah

Comment: Basically, it means, "This concludes the meaningful part of my most recent communication—and in case you're wondering, I still agree with what I just said."

Comment: What I'm about to tell you works exactly the way you would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So yeah" is a [filler phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29) in English, especially for the younger American generations.

There are a few specific uses of "so yeah".  When starting the sentence, it most commonly is used as an [interjection to get conversation started](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/so,-yeah).  Or, as [a pause](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=so%20yeah) while the person gathers their thoughts.

When ending a sentence, it often is used in places where the spoken emphasis and pacing of the sentence are inconsistent with the content, so the speaker uses "so yeah" as a way of completing the sentence.  Lastly, it is sometimes used as a way to [wrap up a speech or thought](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/so-yeah), in a similar way that "over" is used on the radio. So yeah.

Comment: In my personal experience, it's more than "over". It's more like saying "QED" or "I've finished making my point". I've also used it as in "Everything is ready for tonight. So, yeah, I don't think we'll have a problem."